# I have Android Studio installed on Mac (Catalina), keytool error: 'To use the “keytool” command-line tool you need to install a JDK'

Tags: java, macos, macos-catalina

I am trying to run the keytool from the command line and I am getting the following error:

To use the “keytool” command-line tool you need to install a JDK

I have Android Studio installed so I assume that I have the JDK someplace.

I went to my /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines directory and I do not see anything. echo $JAVA_HOME returns nothing.

I was hoping I just needed to point to the right directory and run it but I cannot find it. Was the JDK installed under Android Studio or should I install it? If so what is the best method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing OpenJDK.

Answer (score 2):

When I simply entered `keytool` in Terminal on my Mac, it gave me the same error. Then I looked for the path of this program, which is `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin` for me. On Terminal, I changed directory to this path,

```
cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin
```

Then I was able to run keytool command with

```
./keytool
```

Hope someone finds this helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do `java -version` and it will show you the JRE and JDK version you have installed currently.

This might also help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F575EB4A-70D3-4AB4-A20E-DBE95171AB5F

Comment: Thanks for answering. I installed OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

As the new AndroidStudio version is now out :

[image: Android Studio]

The new path is : `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`